# How to format now function in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, time, format

Is there a way to format mysql NOW()
So i would get something like year month day hours minutes seconds, all together, like this:

20130822143222

or to get something like microtime() in PHP, but for MySQL?

I need it for the trigger before insert. Thank you :)

Comment: @echo_Me: and a large number of those answers will be wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y%m%d%H%i%s')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select date_format(NOW(),'%Y%m%d%H%i%s') as date_val
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use string replace functions to remove dashes, colons and spaces from the output of `NOW()` as it just returns a string that has exactly what you want, separated by punctuation is listed above. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace

Answer (score 0):

Using EXTRACT function:

```
"Select EXTRACT(YEAR from NOW()) as year, EXTRACT(MONTH from NOW()) as month, EXTRACT(DAY
from NOW()) as day, EXTRACT(HOUR from NOW()) as hour, EXTRACT(MINUTE from NOW()) as  
minute, EXTRACT(SECOND from NOW()) as second, EXTRACT(MICROSECOND from NOW()) as 
microsecond, EXTRACT(MINUTE_MICROSECOND from NOW()) as minute_microsecond";
```

Comment: Have you tested that? Does it work? The EXTRACT function could be used, but the expression would be something like `EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM NOW()) * 100000000 + EXTRACT(DAY_SECOND FROM NOW())`

Answer (score 0):

Besides `DATE_FORMAT` this should work too: `SUBSTRING(NOW() + 0, 1, 8)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

```
select UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW());
```

*Jost

Comment: @Maerlyn Have a look at the definition of [php microtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) - this was also an acceptable option according to the question.

Comment: @Jost: UNIX_TIMESTAMP function returns a value in seconds, not microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql use Now() function to date & DATE_FORMAT function sql .

```
select DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%d/%m/%Y %H:%i:%s') as date;;
```

Output:

date

24/01/2024 15:54:32